# sfdx: No such file or directory when launching from command line

Tags: salesforcedx

This has been going on for past couple of weeks. I have been just using my old projects to make do of my work

- I already uninstalled the CLI and reinstalled the latest version.
- followed other solutions here on Salesforce Stackexchange to not no avail. Please help

Here is the output:

> 17:17:24.375 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias vscodeOrg --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
> /Users/username/.local/share/sfdx/client/bin/sfdx: line 16: /Users/username/.local/share/sfdx/client/bin/../7.110.0-85b006b/bin/sfdx: No such file or directory

Comment: Are you using the npm or a binary installer? What OS are you using? What shell?

Comment: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1104

Comment: Catalina (10.15.6), binary install, bash Shell. BTW thanks for updating the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the below comment to resolve this issue.

[image]

You can track the latest updates on this issue here: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1104 (thanks identigral!)

Comment: thanks mubs!  this worked for me